# Switch function in update query

Tags: function, ms-access, switch-statement

I have a table that gets appended with data. The columns are always the same. One column displays `Employee_Type`. When I append data it is displayed as 1, 2, 3 or 4. 1=None, 2=Employee, 3=Contractor, 4=Visitor. I want an update query to run each morning. I was trying an update query where the `Update To` field said :

```
Switch("1","None","2","Employee","3","Contractor","4","Visitor")
```

However, it just changes all cells to `None`, regardless of value. Can anyone help me, or give a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Choose` for this:

```
Choose([Employee_Type],"None","Employee","Contractor","Visitor")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have defined Employee_Type as Text.

Then Switch() should be called as

```
Switch(<employee type field>="1", "None", ...)
```

Since the first conditional test is

```
"1"
```

Which will always be non-zero, and therefore return True.

You have not specified which field you are testing for "1", "2", "3", "4".

Also is that field a of type Text or is it a Number?

If it is a Number, then you need to change to:

```
Switch(<employee type field>=1,"None", ...)
```

Comment: This is placed in an update query?  In the update to or criteria?